# Does Codeigniter active records queries support MS sql (sqlsrv)

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, activerecord

I have to start a project in CI but with Ms sql database.
I am confused does CI active records query will support that type of Database?
Like the following query will support ?

```
$query = $this->db->get('use');
```

Comment: if you've installed this drivers properly (sqlsrv-pdo) - yes CI supports it.

Comment: @sintakonte are you sure about it ? have you try it at CI 3 ?

Comment: i've used it a ton of times especially in combination with some big ERP Systems like MS Dynamics NAV and it worked like a charm - why ? Whats your problem ?

Comment: its get connected but active record queries not working.

Comment: In your query, is "use" the name of your table?

Comment: whats your error - nobody can guess whats your problem is - if you don't post your error message or something like that ;)